# Capture event from native window in Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

So I can open a native window with eg:

```
chrome.windows.create({ url: 'chrome://bookmarks', type: 'popup'})
```

and I can get window id with:

```
chrome.windows.get(integer windowId, object getInfo, function callback)
```

The problem is how do I get window id from the native apps? I need to know when eg. `chrome://bookmarks` popup has been closed...

Comment: Why are you calling the result of opening `chrome://bookmarks` as a popup window a "native window"? Why are you not getting the `windowId` from the callback for [`chrome.windows.create()`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/windows#property-create-callback)? It's then a simple matter of listening to [`chrome.windows.onRemoved`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/windows#event-onRemoved). Or are you meaning an actual OS native window (which is what using that text implies, but is counter-indicated by your code)?

Comment: chrome.windows.create({ url: 'chrome://bookmarks', type: 'popup'}, function(Window) { console.log(Window) })) returns nothing?

Comment: My testing indicates it returns the expected [Window object](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/windows#type-Window). with [`id`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/windows#property-Window-id). There does not appear to be anything special wrt. `chrome.windows.create()` about using `chrome://bookmarks`. A window opens with the Bookmark Manager, and the accurate Window object is returned. That's what is expected.

Comment: Could you post the exact script you are using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally got it working:

```
chrome.windows.create({ url: 'chrome://bookmarks', type: 'popup' }, function (win) {
      var windowId = win.id
      chrome.windows.onRemoved.addListener(function (windowId) {
        console.log(windowId)
      })
    })
```